# How to split an n-bit pin into n 1-bit wires [in Logisim]

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

For example, I want to take a 4-bit pin A and find a way to split it into 4 1-bit wires to it is functionally the same as the B pins. Also, how would I scale this up to a 16-bit pin for 16 1-bit wires. Once again, this is in Logisim version 3.8.0. I would like to do this using only non-advanced components from gates, plexers, and arithmetic if possible.

[image]

Comment: (Once you have accumulated 300 "reputation", you *can create* tags - and should have an idea when that is useful.)

Comment: tip: don't end your question title with something in [square brackets], because that formatting is used here to indicate question status (e.g. [Closed] or [Migrated]), so seeing square brackets at the end of the question title makes me kind of "tune it out" as something that's already been taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

The Splitter component in the wiring folder can accomplish this